# Hive connection is getting closed with error

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to hive and I have installed it with derby db as its driver. But while i am trying to enter hive shell it is showing Connection is already closed. Below is the whole error. Please help to get a resolution to remove the error.Also let me know in comment if you want to see any configurations or xml.

Error:

````
**SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar
!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j
12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configurati
on: logging only errors to the console.
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://
com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang
/Object;)V
Beeline version 2.1.0 by Apache Hive
com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang
/Object;)V
Connection is already closed.**

hive-site-

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration><property> <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name> 
<value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value> 
<description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property><property> 
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name> 
<value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</value> 
<description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property> 
<name>hive.server2.enable.impersonation</name> 
<description>Enable user impersonation for HiveServer2</description>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication</name> 
<value>NONE</value>
<description> Client authentication types. NONE: no authentication check LDAP: LDAP/AD based authentication KERBEROS: Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication CUSTOM: Custom authentication provider (Use with property hive.server2.custom.authentication.class) </description>
</property>
<property>
<name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
<value>True</value>
</property>
</configuration>```
````

Comment: can you share your `hive-site.xml` ?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-22915 & https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-22718

Comment: @smart_coder i have attached the hive-site.xml above. I have tried the above jira solution also but then getting different error with same connection already closed. Please help

Comment: @smart_coder can you please help?

Comment: is it in your local or your cluster you are using and what is your hive version?

Comment: Its in my local and hive version is 2.1.0 @sathya

Answer (score 0):

I just tried these commands and it worked in my case:

```
$ ssh localhost
$ start-all.sh
$ beeline
> !connect jdbc:hive2://
```